# How to print a data outside a range using sqldf in R?

Tags: r, range, mapping, sqldf

I have written a code to map certain positions (in numbers) to a range of positions (range of numbers)

```
library(sqldf)
library(tcltk)
setwd('G:\\Ann\\op\\')
a <- sqldf("select * from file1test f1 inner join file2 f2 on (f1.POS > f2.Start and f1.POS<= f2.Stop) ")
write.table(a, file = "op",sep="\t")
```

**file1test** contains a column position POS consisting of the values

```
POS
5757
7456
1212
4567
9870
2350
```

and **file2** contains two columns Start and Stop

```
Start   Stop
5751    5758
7440    7460
1201    1224
4560    4569
```

and the output from the code generated was like

```
POS    Start    Stop
5757    5751    5758
1212    1201    1224
4567    4560    4569
7456    7440    7460
```

but now I need to print the positions which are outside the range as well, like the following

```
POS    Start    Stop
5757    5751    5758
7456    7440    7460
1212    1201    1224
4567    4560    4569
9870  
2350
```

Comment: Use a `left join`?

Comment: Try: `sqldf("select * from file1test f1 left outer join file2 f2 on (f1.POS > f2.Start and f1.POS <= f2.Stop)")`